# Error creating (javax.sql.XADataSource) Datasource (Microsoft SQLServer) with Payara server: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: isEC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, java-8, payara

When I try to create a JDBC connection pool with SQL Server driver version 7, targeting Payara server version 5, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception while running a command java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: isEC
```

I'm using JDK 8 version jdk1.8.0_191 on Windows.

*IMPORTANT:* With Payara version 4.1 I don't have any error.

Errror log:

```
[#|2018-12-26T13:16:01.709-0500[1;91m|GRAVE|[0mPayara 5.183|[1;94mjavax.enterprise.system.core|[0m_ThreadID=58;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(4);_TimeMillis=1545848161709;_LevelValue=1000;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00003;|
  Exception while running a command
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: isEC
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.getActiveProtocols(Handshaker.java:790)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:549)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1482)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1351)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1688)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1977)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:704)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.createNewConnection(SQLServerPooledConnection.java:59)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.<init>(SQLServerPooledConnection.java:41)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAConnection.<init>(SQLServerXAConnection.java:30)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource.getXAConnection(SQLServerXADataSource.java:50)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource.getXAConnection(SQLServerXADataSource.java:83)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:119)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:618)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.testConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:430)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.pingConnectionPool(ConnectorRuntime.java:1162)
        at org.glassfish.connectors.admin.cli.PingConnectionPool.execute(PingConnectionPool.java:143)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
```

Comment: off-topic is same that question is in 2 pages?? i try to solve this on spanish or english.. but I have no answer from 2 ways..

Comment: The error suggests that the classloader loaded a different class than `sun.security.ssl.Handshaker` was compiled against. And the version loaded is missing a field. This would suggest that your classpath is dirty (contains multiple conflicting instances of the same class).